# Divide and write raster in GDAL using Python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, rioxarray

I have a folder of raster `.tif.` files. I want to iterate through all the rasters in this folder and divide them by a specific raster. I then want to take these outputs and write them to new rasters.

Here is what I am trying:

```
d = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
test = 'test.tif'
folder = Path('Path/to/My/Folder')

for f in folder.glob("*.tif"):
    if any(color in f.name for color in d):
        new_raster = f/test
```

What I am doing here is this: In my folder, I have many raster `.tif` files. However, I only actually want to use them in my loop code if their file names contain "Blue", "Red" or "Green". So I would want to use the files `Blue_Raster.tif`, `Red_Raster.tif`, and `Green_Raster.tif` in my loop, but exclude a `Purple_Raster.tif`, etc. So then FOR EACH of these rasters, I want to divide them by my selected raster `test.tif`. This produces FOR EACH of my rasters (just for Blue, Red, and Green) a `new_raster`, which I want to write to an output raster, titled either `Blue_Output_raster.tif`, `Red_Output_raster.tif`, or `Green_Output_raster.tif`. However, I am not sure how to actually write these rasters. Would this just involve a simple use of the `writeraster()` function in `gdal`? I am not sure if there are actually many more steps involved or if I even used the raster division here correctly. I am open to using `rasterio` or `geocube` as well if that is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with what you require. Read about rasterio write [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html)

```py
d = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
test = 'test.tif'
folder = Path('Path/to/My/Folder')

with rasterio.open("test.tif") as src:
  
  for f in folder.glob("*.tif"):
    if any(color in f.name for color in d):
      
      with rasterio.open(f) as med:    
        new_raster = med.read(1)/src.read(1)

      # write raster
      profile = src.profile
      profile.update(
          dtype=new_raster.dtype,
          count=1,
          compress='lzw')
      filename = "_output_".join(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split("_"))
      with rasterio.open(f'{filename}.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
          dst.write(new_raster, 1)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this helpful suggestion. I tried it, but am having some trouble getting it to work, and received this error: `RasterioIOError: Attempt to create new tiff file 'Colors_output_Test\Output_output_Raster_output_Red_output_value.tif' failed: No such file or directory`. It seems that something in the file paths is just acting up. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: It seems your raster name contains double underscore or it might be that you are trying to rerun the program. Try deleting the newly created file or change the output directory

Answer (score 1):

rioxarray can simplify that:

https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject_match.html

https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-raster-data-python/raster-data-processing/subtract-rasters-in-python/

https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/geospatial-python/07-raster-calculations/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
# Look at this simple code:

import os
import gdal


path = r'inputpath_directory'


# for Loop
 
bands = []

for i in os.listdir(path):
    bands.append(i)
    
print(bands) # a list of bands


# To save a raster using gdal:


gdal_array.SaveArray(bands, 
                     r'outputpath_name', 
                     "GTiff", 
                      prototype=ds) # band prototype
```